# How to get only the raw values from python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python dictionary `dict = {'var0': x, 'var1': z}`

```
type(x) = <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
type(z) = <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

I need the raw values to create a `sympy` function like this:

```
func = Function('g')(x,z) # with out '', x and y not string data type, its sympy symbols
```

Basically `x,z` in the above `Function` command has to come from the dictionary values. How can I achieve this?

lets say dictionary has 3 items `dict = {'var0': x, 'var1': z, 'var2': m}` then the function command should build `func = Function('g')(x,z,m)`

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes we can do that but what if dictionary has 4 items, this has to be dynamic

Comment: something like `Function('g')(*{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}.values())`? this will call function with three args 1,2,3

Comment: I don't understand yet if this is a question about SymPy or a question about dictionaries (in which case it would be irrelevant that you are using SymPy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If dictionary has keys in the same order as function then just unpack values of the dictionary:

```
mydict = {'var0': x, 'var1': z, 'var2': m}
Function('g')(*mydict.values())
```

this will be equivalent to `Function('g')(x, z, m)`